# How to use CUDA constant memory in a programmer pleasant way?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header, linker, cuda

I'm working on a number crunching app using the CUDA framework. I have some static data that should be accessible to all threads, so I've put it in constant memory like this:

```
__device__ __constant__ CaseParams deviceCaseParams;
```

I use the call cudaMemcpyToSymbol to transfer these params from the host to the device:

```
void copyMetaData(CaseParams* caseParams)
{
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol("deviceCaseParams", caseParams, sizeof(CaseParams));
}
```

which works.

Anyways, it seems (by trial and error, and also from reading posts on the net) that for some sick reason, the declaration of deviceCaseParams and the copy operation of it (the call to cudaMemcpyToSymbol) must be in the *same file*. At the moment I have these two in a .cu file, but I really want to have the parameter struct in a .cuh file so that any implementation could see it if it wants to. That means that I also have to have the copyMetaData function in the a header file, but this messes up linking (symbol already defined) since both .cpp and .cu files include this header (and thus both the MS C++ compiler and nvcc compiles it).

Does anyone have any advice on design here?

**Update:** See the comments

Comment: Are you sure they must be in the same file, and not merely in the same translation unit?  (i.e. the declaration could be in the header file, which then gets #included into the source file).

Comment: I tried that for a couple of mins ago and it seems you're right. I don't understand what went wrong when I tried that last time though. It works now for sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

With an up-to-date CUDA (e.g. 3.2) you should be able to do the memcpy from within a different translation unit if you're looking up the symbol at runtime (i.e. by passing a string as the first arg to `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` as you are in your example).

Also, with Fermi-class devices you can just malloc the memory (`cudaMalloc`), copy to the device memory, and then pass the argument as a const pointer. The compiler will recognise if you are accessing the data uniformly across the warps and if so will use the constant cache. See the CUDA Programming Guide for more info. Note: you would need to compile with `-arch=sm_20`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using pre-Fermi CUDA, you will have found out by now that this problem doesn't just apply to constant memory, it applies to anything you want on the CUDA side of things. The only two ways I have found around this are to either:

1. Write everything CUDA in a single file (.cu), or
2. If you need to break out code into separate files, restrict yourself to headers which your single .cu file then includes.

If you need to share code between CUDA and C/C++, or have some common code you share between projects, option 2 is the only choice. It seems very unnatural to start with, but it solves the problem. You still get to structure your code, just not in a typically C like way. The main overhead is that every time you do a build you compile *everything*. The plus side of this (which I think is possibly why it works this way) is that the CUDA compiler has access to all the source code in one hit which is good for optimisation.